# Get current user in ASP.NET 5 beta 6 controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For ASP.NET 5 beta 6, when creating a controller it seems you no longer extend Controller (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller).  So how would I get access to the current user?  Previously I just used the "User" property off Controller to get the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal for user associated with the executing action.  Without Controller, now "User" is no longer defined.

Works in Beta 5:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserDetailsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var claims = from c in user.Claims
                     select new
                     {
                         type = c.Type,
                         value = c.Value
                     };

        return new JsonResult(claims);
    }
}
```

Does not work in Beta 6:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserDetailsController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal; // ERROR - The name 'User' does not exist in the current context
        var claims = from c in user.Claims
                     select new
                     {
                         type = c.Type,
                         value = c.Value
                     };

        return new JsonResult(claims);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I spent longer than I want to admit tonight searching for the answer to how I can get access to the current user using the new POCO style controllers and of course soon after I posted the question I stumbled across the answer while reading through ASP.NET's [announcements repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/).  Hopefully this helps someone else out there.

The POCO styled controller should be:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserDetailsController
{
    [ActionContext]
    public ActionContext ActionContext { get; set; }

    public HttpContext HttpContext => ActionContext.HttpContext;

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User;
        var claims = from c in user.Claims
                     select new
                     {
                         type = c.Type,
                         value = c.Value
                     };

        return new JsonResult(claims);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could even add `public ClaimsPrincipal User => HttpContext?.User;` for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

In beta6 the [`Controller`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-beta6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs) base class no longer comes with the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core` package, but with the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures` package.

So adding a reference to [`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures) will fix your issue. The `Controller` class still lives in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` namespace.

Also see this announcement: [Refactoring of MVC packages](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/49).